# Annotate using greenDAO for custom object

Tags: android, greendao

I want to use a Custom object and store it using greenDAO3. Here is my code -

```
@Entity
public class Books{

@Id(autoincrement = true)
private Long id;
private double LATITUDE;
private double LONGITUDE;
private Date LASTSYNC;

@NotNull
private FeedbackStatus FEEDBACK;
private long TIMESTAMP;
}
```

As you can see FEEDBACK is a custom object and I need it to store it in my DB. But how do I annotate ? There is no good documentation for using foreign key in greenDAO3 annotation.

Could you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ToOne` or `@ToMany` as per your requirement.

I think `@ToMany` is suit for you, because one `Book` is related to many `Feedback`.

Checkout this good [documentation](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/updating-to-greendao-3-and-annotations/), it explains well, & i think it solve all your doubts.